# Redirect back with errors and input in custom request class : Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I had some original code that shows like below with form validation and saving process in MySQL Database.

**Original Code**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $v = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:25|min:5'
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return \Redirect::back()
                    ->withErrors($v)
                    ->withInput();
    }
    ...
    //code to save the record in database is here....
    ...
}
```

**[Then I followed this article](http://slashnode.com/mastering-form-validation-laravel-5/)** and modified the above function and now it looks like below.

```
public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
{

    ...
    //code to save the record in database is here....
    ...
}
```

**and below is the Request class**

```
class CategoryRequest extends Request
{
    protected $redirect = \Redirect::back()->withErrors($v)->withInput();
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:25|min:5'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Error Details**

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

This error is coming at below line.

```
protected $redirect = \Redirect::back()->withErrors($v)->withInput();
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: You can't execute code when defining properties. A properry must be a static value such as string/array etc.

Comment: Where should I write the code to redirect back with errors and input ?

Comment: I believe by default Laravel will already redirect you back to the previous page with errors. There is a response method you can use to define the error response.

Comment: I have posted an answer with an example of how you can also define a custom response. The response/validation classes are very powerful and worth a  good play with.

Comment: As mentioned properties cannot be defined with dynamic initial values, if they need to be initialized dynamically it should be done in a constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to tell Laravel what to do when validation fails. One method is to overwrite the response() method and set your own response as follows...

```
class CategoryRequest extends Request
{
    public function response(array $errors){
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors($errors)->withInput();
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:25|min:5'
        ];
    }
}
```

Laravel's default response is to redirect you to the previous page with errors and input values so the above code is probably not required in your case.

Comment: The rules function is just PHP so you could make rules do whatever you want them to so long as it returns an array of rules.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8 the above has changed, so the `response` function did not work for me, `getRedirectUrl` on the other hand did. Here's a code snippet

```
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    $url = $this->redirector->getUrlGenerator();
    return $url->previous();
}
```